# Dynamic TypeRegistration in Autofac C# using an Unknown type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to create an autofac container that is passed a list of services to register for use in across a number of projects.

I've got the base container builder with all the required types across a number of properties, however I need to then inject a list of services from the class using this base.

what I have:

```
        private void buildAutofacContainer(IServiceCollection services, List<ServiceDescriptor> servicesToAdd)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register(x => new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build()).As<IConfigurationRoot>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<LoggingInterceptor>();
        builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>().As<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationEngine>().As<IApplicationEngine>();
        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationSettings>().As<IApplicationSettings>();
        builder.RegisterType<PortalUnitOfWorkFactory>().As<IPortalUnitOfWorkFactory>();
        builder.RegisterType<DataConnectionService>().As<IDataConnectionService>();
        builder.Populate(services);
        this.Container = builder.Build();
    }
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
            servicesToAdd.ForEach(o =>
        {
            object concrete = o.ImplementationInstance;
            Type type = o.ImplementationType;
            builder.RegisterType<concrete>().As<type>();
        });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If the goal was to add list of service descriptors to your Autofac container/container builder, you could populate those descriptors into `services` as `IServiceCollection` is a collection of service descriptors.

```
    void BuildBaseContainer(IServiceCollection services, List<ServiceDescriptor> servicesToAdd)
    {
        foreach (var descriptor in servicesToAdd)
        {
            services.Add(descriptor);
        }

        var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Populate(servicesToAdd);
        this.Container = builder.Build();
    }
```

Or if your goal was to register an object/instance as an type known only at runtime, you could use the non-generic `As(params Type[])` method and pass the type to the method:

```
// Could also use descriptor.ImplementationType depends on your ServiceDescriptor.
var concreteType = descriptor.ImplementationInstance.GetType();
builder.RegisterType(concreteType)
        .As(descriptor.ImplementationType) // As implementation type
        .As(<other type>) // As any other type
        .AsSelf() // As the object's type
        .As(descriptor.ImplementationInstance.GetType()) // As the implementation instance type
        .AsImplementedInterfaces() // As all implemented interface types
        ;
```

Comment: I thought of that originally, however I don't believe that will register the type within the container.

Comment: Right. If your service descriptors were created using instances, populating them into service collection would only have instances registered, not types. There are non-generic methods you could use when registering types only known at runtime, see if my updates would help.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to be going a different direction for this, but will mark as answer as this helped me understand a lot more. Thanks very much.